# compare multiple values with a variable in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I have logic to compare a variable with multiple values.
For example:

```
logic [3:0] a;
always_comb begin
    flag = (a == 'd13) || (a == 'd2) || (a=='d1); //can this be simplified?
end
```

Is there a easy way to write this statement?

Answer (score 2):

This is more concise using the `inside` operator:

```
always_comb begin
    flag = (a inside {1, 2, 13});
end
```

This is more scalable as well, allowing you to easily add or remove values from the set.

The syntax also supports ranges of values:

```
    flag = (a inside {[1:2], 13});
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.13 *Set membership operator.*

Since the values in the set are all constants, it should be synthesizable (but YMMV).